# How to add a footer table to the next page if space is not available in current page in iText 7

Tags: itext, itext7

I am generating a pdf where we have

- Header(variable height) every page.
- A Table(variable height).
- Footer(variable height) must be in last page only.

Header and footer are getting generated with IEventHandler.
Issue is when the table content is large then it is overlapping with footer,
I am trying to move footer to new page if space is not available but unable to achieve it.

Comment: If the footer is on the last page only, it doesn't make sense to generate it in an event handler. Instead simply add all regular content to the PDF and then check whether on the then last PDF page is enough space for your footer. If there is, add the footer there. Otherwise add yet another page for the footer.

Comment: @mkl then footer content starts from middle of the page if content ends in middle

Comment: *"then footer content starts from middle of the page if content ends in middle"* - only if you add it normally. But you can add the footer content at a fixed position, can't you?

Comment: @mkl I tried this approach but footer is overlapping the content

Comment: @danishahmad Please attach the code you have tried so far and illustrate the visual difference between the current result and the desired result